# SSRS 2016 web portal authentication

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I seem to be getting a problem with the SSRS web portal. If I go to the link, it gives me an error stopping me from seeing the reports, saying

> Could not load folder contents
>
> You are not allowed to view this folder. Contact your administrator to
>   obtain the necessary permissions.

I'm set to a system admin on my machine and on the server itself, and other users with the same permissions do not have this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: As one of the users who can see it, view the folder properties (on the SSRS web page) and look under security. Your domain\username needs to be listed there as at least Browser to view a report.

Answer (score 2):

My laptop was not able to reach our domain to authenticate my account from home.  As soon as I connected to our work VPN, I was able to load the page.

**From the Microsoft.ReportingsServices.Portal.Webhost log:**

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.WindowsAuthz1355ApiException:
>   Windows returned a ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN error when Reporting Services
>   attempted to call the Windows Authz APIs.